# Method to determine what `Type` of systemd service to use for any given application

Tags: systemd, services, startup

I think I have a relatively good handle on the different `Type` of services which systemd can be configured for (e.g. `simple`, `oneshot`, etc).

The [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) provide a pretty reasonable overview and description of the options. So often it's possible to "guess" the likely best option and do 'trial and error' to confirm. That is especially the case with applications that I'm quite familiar with.

However, I am concerned that there may be circumstance I'm not accounting for during my 'trial and error' testing (i.e. risk of edge case bugs). So I'm after suggestions on methods of testing/investigating an application to determine it's likely best `Type`.

FWIW, I'm thinking of some way of manually launching an application and tracing how it responds, whether it forks or not (multiple processes, etc). I feel like there must be some relatively easy way to do that (using standard commandline tools) that I'm missing.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but Debian is my distro of choice.

Comment: Joke on systemd: if there were "some relatively easy way to do that (using standard commandline tools)" they would have either (a) already incorporated that, or (b) re-invented it.

Comment: @muru That is pretty funny! :D

Comment: [I've answered a very similar question on Super User.SE.](https://superuser.com/a/1274913/784449)

Comment: Thanks @telcoM - that's pretty sensible (and simple) advice. TBH on face value, now I read that, it almost seems obvious. Although it's nice to have it so clearly spelt out! :) The next issue is, what to do with this question? I searched fairly extensively prior to posting and didn't come across that thread, so perhaps you should repost your comment as an answer?

Comment: Also consider that often the right answer is not really derive `Type` from a program's behavior (e.g. `Type=forking`) but instead to modify the program's behavior (to not daemonize) in order to use a more appropriate `Type` (such as `Type=simple`). Also more integration with systemd is usually pretty beneficial and often enables powerful features (such as socket activation), so the best answer is that it's up to the developers to provide systemd units together with their code, so they can take full benefit of full integration.

Comment: Good point @filbranden. Obviously that's not so easy when working with someone else's software, although with FLOSS, improvements could always be contributed back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Copied from [my answer on Super User.SE.](https://superuser.com/a/1274913/784449))

When you start the service manually from the command line (without using the `nohup`prefix command or the `&` suffix to run it in the background, or in other words, just run the command you would put on the `ExecStart=` line of the `.service` file), what happens?

**a)** If the service starts and keeps running, and the prompt does not return until you press Control-C or stop the service in some other way: then `Type = simple` is the right choice.

**b)** If the prompt returns but the service keeps running in the background (i.e. the service daemonizes itself on its own), then `Type = forking` is the right choice.

**c)** If the service does its job and returns to the prompt without leaving anything running (i.e. the service just adjusts some kernel settings, sends a command to something else or does something similar), then `Type = oneshot` is probably the right choice. In this case, `ExecStart` of the service might be the command to "set" something, and `ExecStop` would be the corresponding command to "unset" it. This type usually benefits of `RemainAfterExit=true`, so systemd will keep track of the "state" of this service according to whether the thing was most recently "set" or "unset".

The other `Type` values are special cases. For example, if the service utilizes a D-Bus connection, then `Type = dbus` might be the best choice. It makes `systemd` aware of the fact, and then systemd will track this service (and anything that depends on it) by the presence of this service on the D-Bus.

To use `Type = notify`, the process must be able to connect to Unix socket specified in environment variable `$NOTIFY_SOCKET` and to report its status by writing messages to that socket whenever necessary. Also, the service file should specify the `NotifyAccess` option to grant access to the notification socket as appropriate.

There is a command-line utility `systemd-notify` and a C library function `sd_notify(3)` you may use to send these messages, but if neither of those is suitable to your requirements, you can just implement your own message sender. The messages required are very simple, and look like shell variable assignments: for example, to notify that the service has successfully completed startup and is ready to serve any incoming requests, the service should send the string equivalent to the output of `printf "READY=1\n"` to the socket. See `man 3 sd_notify` for more details on the recognized messages.

Note: many service applications designed to be portable to many Unix-style systems may behave as b) by default, but can be made to work like a) by adding an option (usually described as "don't fork", "keep running in foreground", "don't daemonize" or similar). In that case, if the option has no other side effects, then adding the option and using the a)-type behavior would be preferable for `systemd`.

Comment: I've got "ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo -u someuser /usr/bin/someprogram" with "PIDFile=/var/run/somefile".   Using "Type=Simple" prints "Supervising process XXXX which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits", but "Type=Forking" hangs until it times out because the sudo doesn't exit.  Which type should I use instead?

Comment: @PFudd Instead of using `sudo -u someuser` as part of the `ExecStart=` command, specify the user directly in the service definition as `User=someuser`. If the program requires something in someuser's login script, find out what it is, and add the necessary environment settings, ulimits, etc. to the service definition. Making the program's requirements explicit like that may take some effort, but you'll thank yourself later when it's time to move your setup to a new major OS release or new hardware.

Comment: The reason I switched from `User=someuser` to `User=root` is because the program expects `/var/run/someprogram` to exist.  The `ExecStartPre=` line now says `/usr/bin/install -d -o someuser -g somegroup -m 755 /var/run/someprogram`.  I used to have it say `ExecStartPre=+/usr/bin/install...`, but the `+` feature isn't available on older versions of systemd.

Comment: For the curious, someprogram is `zabbix_agent2` and someuser is `zabbix`.  The version of `systemd` that doesn't have the `+` feature is `219`.  A version of `systemd` with that feature is `249`.  Zabbix expects `/var/run/zabbix` to exist and be writable by the `zabbix` user, but on Ubuntu 22.04 (at least), `/var/run` is a tmpfs.

Comment: The zabbix-agent2 package creates `/var/run/zabbix` on install and expects it to live forever.  Oh, and the `+` feature means "run this command with full privileges" (i.e. as root).

Comment: @PFudd Are you aware of `systemd-tmpfiles(8)`, or does it not exist in the older systemd versions you'll have to support? That would be the expected way to have files or directories with specific permissions prepared in tmpfs filesystems.

Comment: I was not aware of `systemd-tmpfiles(8)`, no.  I can see that it would definitely solve the problem for good and for all time; it almost looks like a Turing-complete language.  So, create `/etc/tmpfiles.d/zabbix.conf` with the contents `d /var/run/zabbix 755 zabbix zabbix`?  The `zabbix` user is not there at boot, it's a network-based user via `sssd`.  Can `systemd-tmpfiles` handle users who show up later?

Comment: Oh, the `tmpfiles.d(5)` manpage says this: "System daemons frequently require private runtime directories below /run/ to store communication sockets and similar. For these, it is better to use `RuntimeDirectory=` in their unit files (see systemd.exec(5) for details), if the flexibility provided by tmpfiles.d is not required."

Comment: This is great!  All I needed in the override file was `RuntimeDirectory=zabbix`, and it's all sorted out!  Thank you!